# how to log offset value after consuming in spring kafka

Tags: spring-kafka

I got the rebalance issue in Kafka Consumer and able to solve by setting correct value for max.poll.interval.ms.
But Currently I have seen some of the transaction missing.
So wanted to see the logs which offset value not processed.

So how I can see the logs in spring Kafka.
I am using spring Kafka version 2.2.2.RELEASE

Comment: you can also use error handler https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#listener-error-handlers

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `@KafkaListener`, you can add `@Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) long offset` as a parameter to the listener method.

Also, you can set the `commitLogLevel` container property on the `containerProperties` to INFO and the container will log all commits at that level.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.3.3.RELEASE/api/index.html?org/springframework/kafka/listener/ConsumerProperties.html

(`ContainerProperties` is s subclass of `ConsumerProperties` in 2.3).